# In node.js, how can I auto input the password with sudo command in exec?

Tags: node.js, exec, stdin, child-process

I'm developing a Node.js program and encounter a problem.

I try to use stdin.write to auto input the password of sudo in exec, but it seems not works.

I don't want run my program as root.

Here is my code:

```
var SUDO_PASSWORD = '123456';
var command = 'sudo echo "1" > test.txt';
var child = require('child_process').exec(command);
child.on('exit', function() {
    console.log('in exit');
    return 'OK';
});
child.stdin.write(SUDO_PASSWORD);
```

How to modify it? Thank everybody.

Comment: Hi, Please let me know how did you solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

We have the same problem, need to do a root operation but don't want application to run with root prvileges.
So we start the application from root and then drop roots privileges using

```
 if (!/^win|^darwin/i.test(require('os').platform())) {
        try {
            console.log('I am ' + process.getuid());
            process.setgid('user');
            process.setuid('user');
            console.log('I now am ' + process.getuid());
        } catch (err) {
            console.error("Unable to drop root privileges, exiting\n" + err.message, [err.stack]);
            process.exit();
        }
    }
```

I know this is not what you want but maybe can solve your problem.

Comment: Hi xflofoxx, thank you for reply, but it can not solve my problem. That's because I can't run the command with sudo when I changed to the normal user. In my situation, it will run on normal user, but sometimes need to run as root.